# Xamarin UIButton has multiple event handlers

Tags: ios, events, xamarin, uibutton, handler

I am running into an issue with UIButtons within cells having multiple event handlers assigned to them within Xamarin. Is there a way to ensure that only one event handler is assigned? I assumed that when reloading a tableview or collectionview that anything in those cells would be released/reset. Is that incorrect?

Here is where I setup the cell in the delegate:

```
public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
        {
            EventHandler clickTarget = (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (this.parantController.showCategories)
                {
                    this.parantController.apiCallGetBusinessesIndustries(this.parantController.businessesCategoriesResponseModel.business_categories[indexPath.Row].id);
                    this.parantController.showIndustries = true;
                    this.parantController.showCategories = false;
                }
                else  if (this.parantController.showIndustries)
                {
                    this.parantController.apiCallGetBusinessessList("", this.parantController.businessesIndustriesResponseModel.business_industries[indexPath.Row].id);
                    this.parantController.filterView.Hidden = true;
                    this.parantController.showVerticalList = false;
                    this.parantController.showIndustries = false;
                    this.parantController.clearAll = true;
                    this.parantController.filterCollectionView.ReloadData();
                    this.parantController.clearAll = false;
                    //this.parantController.showCategories = true;
                }
            };

            var cell = (FilterCollectionCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell("filterCollectionCell", indexPath);
            if (this.parantController.businessesCategoriesResponseModel.business_categories != null && !this.parantController.showIndustries)
            {
                cell.updateCell(false, this.parantController.businessesCategoriesResponseModel.business_categories[indexPath.Row].name, clickTarget);
            }
            if (this.parantController.showIndustries)
            {
                cell.updateCell(false, this.parantController.businessesIndustriesResponseModel.business_industries[indexPath.Row].name, clickTarget);
            }

            return cell;
        }
```

Here is the code where I add the event handler to the button in the cell view controller:

```
public void updateCell(Boolean selectedFilterType, string title, EventHandler clickHandler) {

        btnFilter.RemoveTarget(this, null, UIControlEvent.AllEvents);

        btnFilter.AddTarget(clickHandler, UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);// = handlerToUse;

        this.btnFilter.SetTitle(title, UIControlState.Normal);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FilterCollectionCell` creation should handle applying events to the cell so when a cell is reused you are not appending a new Event each time within the `GetCell` method.

Otherwise you can retrieve all the UButtons' targets and remove them each time a cell is requested:

```
foreach (var target in button.AllTargets)
{
    button.RemoveTarget(target, null, UIControlEvent.AllTouchEvents);
}
```

Comment: How would I handle applying events in FilterCollectionCell?

Comment: @SushiHanover Any guidance?